# Downgrade data from MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql

I need to downgrade data  from MySQL  5.7 to MySQL 5.1. are there  any ways to do in simple steps? (backup and restore )T
There is a solution is  step by step like  downgrade from 5.7 to 5.6, and then to 5.5. 
[The Following link says step by step](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/downgrading.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not using features from 5.7, that are not avaliable in 5.1, for example `utf8mb4` encoding (needed for emoji characters)

Then most safe option is to `mysql_dump` all databases via mysqldump, except for `mysql` (actually you need `mysql.user` table, but it's safer to recreate, other settings tables may and most probably will not fit)

Try restoring on staging server first, to see if restored db works the way you expect it to